# Getting all the user's friends that are using the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I know that by the title this question has been asked a lot, but with the new `Facebook 4.0 sdk` this is a problem.

I know that if i call

```
[self FCMSendOpenGraphRequestWithPath:@"me/friends" andCompletionHandler:^(BOOL seccess, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (seccess) {

        }
    }else{

    }
}];
```

I will get all the user's friends that are using my app and that fit into one paging page (i have noticed that one page can hold 25 friends).

My problem is what happens when i need to get the page 2,3,4..etc'?
I know that if i call the graph call with the '`next`' field i will get the next page. But because the `Facebook sdk` uses only `completionHandlers` using recursion won't work, and i don't want to hard code all the method call obviously.

All advices will help,

Thanks

Comment: Why would recursion not work due to completion handlers? If blocks are bothering you check [this](https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/) out.

Comment: thanks i'll read that, can you think of another way of implementing this?

Comment: I guess using the paging functionality with recursion (until there is no `[@"paging"][@"next"]` field in the response would be a good way to deal with this.